# Optimal binary search tree - Cormen

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

[image]

I am looking into optimal binary search tree in Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen etc. For reference I am attaching a [text link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=i-bUBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA399&lpg=PA399&dq=optimal%20binary%20search%20tree%20dynamic%20programming%20example%20cormen&source=bl&ots=YTHXevjI--&sig=xGHnZVMLO2Z2GsjBd9Lg-v6ipDE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CE8Q6AEwCGoVChMInJuRxJXLxwIViRk-Ch0pNg0z#v=onepage&q=optimal%20binary%20search%20tree%20dynamic%20programming%20example%20cormen&f=false).

Here on page 399 we have table which has contribution. I am not able to understand how author calculated this column. For example node k1 contribution is 0.30, k4 is 0.20. How has the author calculated this?

Comment: as usual: the URL of the site might change/the site might be deleted, so pls provide some information about what is on the site.

Comment: added picture for clarify in addition to link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the formula to get search cost in T => **E[search cost in T]=....*(page 398 the bottom)***

To get cost for k1:

```
k1=(depth(k1) + 1) * p1
```

Look at the table is given for value of depth(k1) and p1 *(page 399)*.

```
k1=(1+1)*0.15
  =2*0.15
  =0.3

k2=(0+1)*0.10
  =1*0.10
  =0.10

etc
```

I hope my explanation can help.